# filter an array by key value that has pipes in it

Tags: php, arrays, filter

I have a form that will need to except input from users to filter the search results. I am not the original designer of the form. I one of two ways that I saw to filter the results. A) I could have tried to restrict the sql query to the selected codes or B) filter the results that are returned. I am trying B.

I have tried

```
var_dump(array_intersect_key($array1, $array2));
```

No success:

Array1 looks like this:

```
array (

        '|00006|5' => array('pid' => 111

                'provider_id' => 123456 )  

        '|93000|34' => array('pid' => 112

                'provider_id' => 127654 )

        '|93225|1' => array('pid' => 113

                'provider_id' => 127893 )
```

)

I figured out how the pipes got into the key values and I tried to adjust my keys to match but that did not work either.

Any suggestions on how I can filter these types of results with a key that is not a single value and is dynamically changed?

Array2 look like:

```
  99232 => string '99232' (length=5)
  85610 => string '85610' (length=5)
  93970 => string '93970' (length=5)
  93000 => string '93000' (length=5)
  99406 => string '99406' (length=5)
  99215 => string '99215' (length=5)
```

I made the key value and the string value the same trying to setup some type of filtering.
But since the third value in array1 will be dynamically delivered in a while clause. I have no way of matching that number to the Array2.

My expected outcome is

```
    array (

        '|93000|34' => array('pid' => 112

                'provider_id' => 127654 )
       )
```

As that only one of the 6 inputs matched one of the array1 values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define your key comparison function and then use `array_intersect_ukey()`:

```
$a = array (
        '|00006|5' => array('pid' => 111,
                'provider_id' => 123456 ),
        '|93000|34' => array('pid' => 112,
                'provider_id' => 127654 ),
        '|93225|1' => array('pid' => 113,
                'provider_id' => 127893 ),
);

$b = array('93000' => '93000');

print_r(array_intersect_ukey($a, $b, function($ka, $kb) {
        if ($ka[0] == '|') {                     // transform key
                $ka = substr($ka, 1, strrpos($ka, '|') - 1);
        }
        if ($kb[0] == '|') {                     // transform key
                $kb = substr($kb, 1, strrpos($kb, '|') - 1);
        }
        // perform regular comparison
        return strcmp($ka, $kb);
}));
```

Comment: I have been trying to substitute the print_r with a working variable but I have not been able to do so. I have tried replacing it with $frows = array_intersect_ukey(). And I tried to echo strcmp. What do I use to load this into a working variable?

Comment: @user1846439 Can you write what you have now in a codepad to demonstrate the problem you're having with it?

Comment: Jack, thanks but I finally blundered through it and got the code integrated. Regards

Answer (score 1):

or you can do this.
good luck :)

```
$parsed1 = array();
foreach($array1 as $key => $value) {
    $splited = explode("|", $key);
    $parsed1[$splited[1]] = $value;
}
var_dump(array_intersect_key($parsed1,$array2));
```